# NaN in Javascript string concatenation

Tags: javascript

Take this array:

```
errors [
    "Your name is required.", 
    "An email address is required."
]
```

I am trying to iterate it and create a string like:

```
"Your name is required.\nAn email address is required.\n"
```

Using this code:

```
var errors = ["Your name is required.","An email address is required."];

if (errors) {

    var str = '';

    $(errors).each(function(index, error) {
        str =+ error + "\n";
    });

    console.log(str); // NaN

}
```

I am getting `NaN` in the console. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`=+` is not the same as `+=`. First is `x = +y` and another is `x = x + y`.

`+x` is a shortcut for `Number(x)` literally converting the variable to number. If the operation can't be performed, `NaN` is returned.

`+=` acts like string concatenation when one of the parts (left or right) has a `string` type.

Comment: Another nice thing is + at the end of line and beginning of the next one. Hard to spot and NaNs your string.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you're getting that result is because you are writing `=+` instead of `+=`. It's being treated as:

```
str = (+error) + "\n";
```

`+error` casts `error` to a number, which would be `NaN` because it can't be converted, so there you go.

But you could just do `errors.join("\n")` instead, much easier!